# Typo in help centre?

Tags: discussion, help-center

Quote from [user behaviour](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/behavior) article, emphasis mine:

> The community tends to vote down overt self-promotion and flag it as spam. Post good, relevant answers, and if some (but not all) happen to be about your product or website, that’s okay. However, you must disclose your affiliation in your **answers**.

What if it's a question?

The article goes on to talk about posts in general, but it seems this is a mistake.

Comment: It also says `Post good, relevant answers` -- perhaps this should be changed to content? However, if you are the developer of a product / tool / whatever then any *question* you post is -- I'm going to immediately assume -- posted in bad faith purely for promotion as you should already know the answer or have a better means of acquiring it than random people in the internet.

Comment: In that *particular* case, ("overt self-promotion") - it *tends* to be answers that are relevant...

Comment: @MarcGravell Just had a case pop up today that was a question, and was surprised at the wording!